# Создание меню выбора C++

Tags: c++, menu, if

вообщем нужно создать меню выбора пунктов, например:

1. Создание массива
2. Вывод массива
3. Вставка элемента в начало массива

Я вот думал сделать через if и else if, например:

```
if(punkt==1)
{
//делаем что-то
}
else if (punkt==2)
{
//Делаем что-то
}
```

Но в таком случае я ума не приложу как сделать так, чтобы при выполнении одного пункта можно было выбрать другой не закрывая программы.

Кто подскажет как реализовать?

P.S пытался через функции но никак не могу вывести массив из функции, пробовал часа два в итоге куча ошибок.

Comment: Ну сделайте цикл типа `for(;;) { Вывод меню; Запрос ввода; switch() { действия } }` Среди пунктов меню - что-то для завершения программы, с соответствующей обработкой в `case` (не лепите макароны `if-else if - ...`, для этого есть `switch`).

Comment: @Harry ААА догнал, спасибо сделал, только через while, а не for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int a;
        bool While=true;
        while (While) {
            cin >> a;
            switch (a)
            {
            case 1:
                //код
                break;
            case 2:
                //код
                break;
            case 3:
                //код
                break;
            case 4:
                While = false;
                //выход из цикла
                break;
            default:
                cout << "error\n";
                While = false;
                //если не правильно ввел
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо я уже по ответу Harry понял всё))

Comment: @ТимурБердиев ну я привел пример кода что бы понятней было )